# babel is exporting "this" as undefined in ember computed property

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, babeljs

using `ember-cli@0.2.7` and `emberjs@1.13.2`.

Source emberjs model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    displayName : Ember.computed('name', () => {
      return this.get('name');
    })
});
```

Translated model

```
'use strict';

var _this = undefined;

exports['default'] = DS['default'].Model.extend({
    name: DS['default'].attr('string'),

    displayName: Ember.computed('name', function () {
        return _this.get('name'); //at this point _this is undefined
    })
});
```

The trouble is that _this is never set the the model. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Babel is exporting it as undefined because the context you are preserving using the fat arrow function is undefined.

There is no difference between what you have at the moment and the following:

```
let options = {
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    displayName : Ember.computed('name', () => {
      return this.get('name');
    })
};
console.log(this); // undefined
export default DS.Model.extend(options);
```

The context in this case is undefined. You are passing options to `DS.Model` the object does not exist yet.

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    displayName : Ember.computed('name', function() {
      return this.get('name');
    })
});
```

On an unrelated note, since you're using ember let's make use of ES6 destructuring to make the code look 'nicer':

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { computed } = Ember;
const { attr, Model } = DS;

export default Model.extend({
    name: attr('string'),

    displayName : computed('name', function() {
      return this.get('name');
    })
});
```

Comment: so to me it seams that you can only use the new arrow construct when inside a function.  I would have thought that "this" refers to the parent object in both cases.

Comment: `() => {}` === `function() {}.bind(this)` in your case `this` === `undefined`, there is no parent object yet, you are passing an object of options to `DS.Model` the `DS.Model` instance has not been created yet.

Comment: You only ever use the fat arrow when you want to preserve the context or when the context doesn't matter (aesthetic reasons)

Comment: more recent versions of ember-data allow you to import just the needed classes like so: `import attr from 'ember-data/attr';` and `import Model from 'ember-data/model';`. You can check out the latest ember-cli blueprints for more examples.